# javaFX textarea - columns/rows

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

The textarea-class in JavaFX should give me the option to add rows and columns, but the way I tried didn't work:

```
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setPrefRowCount(100);
    ta.setPrefColumnCount(100);
```

I'm searching for columns/rows like in Microsoft Excel, inclusive the gridines.

`.setGridLinesVisible(true);`

doesn't work for this Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use case similiar to Excel you're actually looking for [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm). Every table cell can contain anything, even another window so it is very flexible.

If you want grid lines on top of TextArea, but want to keep the standard TextArea behavior, you will have to combine the TextArea and TableView in a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html).
You will just have to clear the table's background using CSS.
However, matching the row and column sizes with the text will need some additional code.

Apologies for my English.

Comment: TableView was the solution! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> colums/rows like in Microsoft Excel, inclusive the gridines

[TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) as recommended in Michael's answer is likely the right basic solution for.

There are some 3rd party controls you might consider which add some basic spreadsheet like functionality to the base JavaFX TableView control:

1. [SpreadsheetView](http://fxexperience.com/2013/08/announcing-controlsfx-8-0-2-developer-preview-1/) from the [ControlsFX project](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).
2. [TiwulFX](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) from Panemu.

Comment: I think this would also be ok, but I don't want to use 3rd party libraries at the point where I'm staying. But thanks for your answer! :)